# Inserting struct in mongodb in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to insert a struct in mongo database.

```
type SecretsStruct struct {
   UserID string `bson:"userid" json:"userid"`
   secretOne string `bson:"secret_one" json:secret_one`
   secretTwo string `bson:"secret_two" json:secret_two`
   secretThree string `bson:"secret_three" json:secret_three`
 }

func (c *SecretsStruct) SetSecrets(userId string, encryptedKeys   
      [][]byte){
   c.UserID = userId
   c.secretOne = hex.EncodeToString(encryptedKeys[0])
   c.secretTwo = hex.EncodeToString(encryptedKeys[1])
   c.secretThree = hex.EncodeToString(encryptedKeys[2])
   log.Printf("This is the c %s", c)
 }

 g := SecretsStruct{}
 g.SetSecrets(userStruct.UserID, encryptedKeys)
 err = secretCollection.Insert(g)
 if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
```

I have tried inserting the byte arrays corresponding to the secrets but of no help. The result which gets populated to the corresponding insertion operation is :

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5b80117c118c660aaa0c87c2'),
'userid': 'eb19d220-ef13-43aa-8a7f-f78637718000'}
```

On the other hand, if I try to insert same data with a map but without struct.

```
secretCollection.Insert(bson.M{"userid": userStruct.UserID,
    "secret_one": encryptedKeys[0],
    "secret_two": encryptedKeys[1],
    "secret_three": encryptedKeys[2]})
```

The insertion operation executes successfully.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to export your struct fields, so that another package (in this case mgo) can access them:

```
type SecretsStruct struct {
    UserID string `bson:"userid" json:"userid"`
    SecretOne string `bson:"secret_one" json:secret_one`
    SecretTwo string `bson:"secret_two" json:secret_two`
    SecretThree string `bson:"secret_three" json:secret_three`
}
```

Comment: My Silly mistake .. Thank you .

Comment: You're welcome. If this really helped, I would be happy about an accept ;)

Comment: took me some time to figure that export in golang means capitalize first letter