# BQ Insert to record type successful not data not inserted

Tags: go, google-bigquery, record, inserter

I'm trying to insert data into Bigquery following the example at
[text](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-inserting-data-types?hl=en) with pre-created table as against the given example.
My code is as follows

```
type tagInfo struct {
    proj_name string `bigquery:"proj_name"`
    Tags      Tags   `bigquery:"tags"`
}
type Tags struct {
    key    string `bigquery:"key"`
    values string `bigquery:"values"`
}
func insertData() error {
    prjName := "prjName"
    datasetID := "DSName"
    tableID := "TName"

    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, prjName)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Bigquery.NewClient: %w", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    item := &tagInfo{
        proj_name: "Devil",
        Tags: Tags{
            key:    "engcontact",
            values: "Meryl Streep",
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("Item is: %s", item)
    items := []*tagInfo{item}

    table := client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID)
    inserter := table.Inserter()
    err = inserter.Put(ctx, items)

    if err != nil {
        if multiErr, ok := err.(bigquery.PutMultiError); ok {
            for _, putErr := range multiErr {
                fmt.Printf("failed to insert row %d with err: %v \n", putErr.RowIndex, putErr.Error())
                fmt.Println(putErr.Errors)
            }
        }
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

The code runs successfully, but I do not see any records inserted.
Table structure is as follows

Field name Type Mod Key Collation Default Value Policy Tags
proj_name     STRING    NULLABLE
tags.         RECORD    NULLABLE
key.        STRING    NULLABLE
values.     STRING    NULLABLE

Not sure what/where is it going wrong, if someone can provide a pointer, hugely appreciated.

TIA
Sreekanth

Expecting the records to be inserted successfully in table.

Comment: Please do not include images in your question, but rather a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields should be exported. These kind of issues are reported too many times:

- JSON: [json.Marshal(struct) returns "{}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327391/json-marshalstruct-returns)
- BSON: [Inserting struct in mongodb in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006453/inserting-struct-in-mongodb-in-golang)
- YAML: [Go Unmarshaling YAML into struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544146/go-unmarshaling-yaml-into-struct)
- TOML: [Not able to read TOML file using Go with BurntSushi library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218484/not-able-to-read-toml-file-using-go-with-burntsushi-library)

```golang
type tagInfo struct {
    ProjName string `bigquery:"proj_name"`
    Tags     Tags   `bigquery:"tags"`
}
type Tags struct {
    Key    string `bigquery:"key"`
    Values string `bigquery:"values"`
}
```

See the doc for [(*Inserter).Put](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Inserter.Put):

> ...
>
> If src is ValueSaver, then its Save method is called to produce a row for uploading.
>
> If src is a struct or pointer to a struct, **then a schema is inferred from it and used to create a StructSaver**. The InsertID of the StructSaver will be empty.
>
> ...

And here is the comment for the [inferFields](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/e0c4cc73587d944175da9e38e9960add89f21dec/bigquery/schema.go#L506-L507) func:

```golang
// inferFields extracts all exported field types from struct type.
func inferFields(rt reflect.Type) (Schema, error) {
```

Comment: Thanks @Zeke Lu, I did indeed figure out that the issue was with the unexported fields of Struct, while I was trying out the example. Thanks for the detailed response. Appreciate it.